# How do I make Matlab help properly display web links for weird URLs?

Tags: url, matlab

Usually if I include, in the file `foo.m`, a comment of the form:

```
% See also: <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/etc">link name</a>
```

the link appears in the help browswer, *i.e.* in Matlab, I issue

```
>> help foo
```

and I get something like

> See also: [link name](http://en.wikipedia.org/etc)

so far so good. However, there are some web addresses that have funny characters, for example:

```
% See also: <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_(statistics)">http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_(statistics)</a>
```

Matlab does not render this correctly in the help browser. When I view the help, it looks like this:

> See also:
> [statistics](http:///home/user/etc/matlab/statistics))">http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_([statistics](http:///home/user/etc/matlab/statistics))

where the link is to the local directory named 'statistics'. I have tried all kinds of quote escapes and backslashes, but cannot get the help browser to work properly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Url-escape the funny characters with character codes.

```
function foo
%FOO Function with funny help links
%
% Link to <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_%28statistics%29">some page</a>.
```

The Matlab urlencode() function will show you what codes to use. But keep the colon and slashes as is.

```
>> disp(urlencode('Kernel_(statistics)'))
Kernel_%28statistics%29
```

Here's a function that will quote the URL path elements, preserving the parts you need to leave intact.

```
function escapedUrl = escape_url_for_helptext(url)

ixColon = find(url == ':', 1);
if isempty(ixColon)
    [proto,rest] = deal('', url);
else
    [proto,rest] = deal(url(1:ixColon), url(ixColon+1:end));
end

parts = regexp(rest, '/', 'split');
encodedParts = cellfun(@urlencode, parts, 'UniformOutput', false);
escapedUrl = [proto join(encodedParts, '/')];

function out = join(strs, glue)

strs(1:end-1) = strcat(strs(1:end-1), {glue});
out = cat(2, strs{:});
```

To use it, just pass in your whole URL.

```
>> escape_url_for_helptext('http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_(statistics)')
ans =
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_%28statistics%29
```

Comment: For completeness, I have to escape in the link text as well: `% See also: <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_%28statistics%29">http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_%28statistics%29</a>`. If I have Kernel_(statistics) inside the `<a ... ></a>` pair, Matlab does not render it correctly.  Thanks for the catch, I'm slapping my head for not seeing it.